# Property of an array cannot be read

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, oop, dynamic

I have an extremely complex page that uses dynamic information to generate a layout with the correct and relevant information.

I am storing the data as an object. I have essentially 15 objects with multiple fields of user-submitted data.

Everything is stored and output correctly on the page, however now I am trying to validate and the information when the user tries to edit it from the edit page. The information is all being generated and laid out correctly, however I keep getting the same errors on the validation of the information.

The validation should go through and determine if a field was filled out correctly, and if it was not record a variable and add it to an alert variable. Then once it i done running the validation function it should pop up an alert with what fields still need to be filled in.

I keep receiving an error when it runs through the for loop toward the bottom. It says 'Uncaught TypeError' Cannot read property 'questionNumber' of undefined.

Above the code below I store the object and the properties, but this function is where everything is going awry. Note that there are also 15 arrays in the qtest object, but for the sake of simplification I removed all but a few.

I have gotten this to work on smaller, simpler forms, however because of the complexity and storage method I think this may be missing something or I might not be accessing something correctly. The code is very long and below, I've scaled back as much as possible. Please, if you have any insight or help you can provide I would be extremely grateful. Thank you!

```
var validateQ = function(qTextID, qAnswerType, TFID, MCID, MCText1, MCText2, MCText3, MCText4, VisRef, Youtube, Vimeo, ImgID) {
    if (document.getElementById('ItemName').value == "") {
        var quizName = true;
    };
    if (jQuery('select[name="CAT_Custom_14"]').val() == 'Quiz') {
        if (jQuery(qTextID).val() == "") {
            var qText = true;
        };
        if (jQuery('CAT_Custom_249').val() == " ") {
            var quizscore1 = true;
        };
        if (jQuery(qAnswerType).val() == " ") {
            var answertype = true;
        } else if (jQuery(qAnswerType).val() == 'True/False') {
            if (!jQuery(TFID).is(':checked')) {
                var tfanswer = true;
                var mcanswer = false;
            };
        } else if (jQuery(qAnswerType).val() == 'Multiple Choice') {
            if (!jQuery(MCID).is(':checked')) {
                var mcanswer = true;
                var tfanswer = false;
            };
                if (jQuery(MCText1).val() == "" || jQuery(MCText2).val() == "" || jQuery(MCText3).val() == "" || jQuery(MCText4).val() == "") {
                    var mcTextfields = true;
                } else {
                    mcTextfields = false;
                };
            };
    } else if (jQuery('select[name="CAT_Custom_14"]').val() == 'Survey') {
        if (jQuery(qTextID).val() == "") {
            var qText = true;
        };
        if (!jQuery(sAnswers1).is(':checked')) {
            var surveyAnswers1 = true;
        } else {
            surveyAnswers1 = false;
        };
    };
        if (jQuery(VisRef).val() != " ") {
            if (jQuery(VisRef).val() == "Youtube Video" && jQuery(Youtube).val() == "") {
                var youtubeVal = true;
            } else if (jQuery(VisRef).val() == "Vimeo Video" && jQuery(Vimeo).val() == "") {
                var vimeoVal = true;
            } else {
                //               validateImage(ImgID);
            };
        } else {
            youtubeVal = false;
            vimeoVal = false;
            var tempImgCheck = false;
        };
        if (numCheck == 15) {
            numCheck = 16;
        };
    var qName = "- Quiz or Survey Name\n";
    var shortDescription = "- A short description of the Quiz/Survey\n";
    var scoreMessage = "- A required passing score\n";
    var QTextMessage = "- Question text\n";
    var answerTMessage = "- An answer type\n";
    var mcFields = "- The Multiple Choice answer fields\n";
    var mcMessage = "- The correct Multiple Choice Answer\n"
    var tfMessage = "- The correct True/False answer\n";
    var vimMessage = "- A Vimeo Video code\n";
    var ytMessage = "- A Youtube Video code\n";
    var imgMessage = "- A reference image\n";
    var surveyMessage = "- An answer type\n";
    if (quizName == true || quizscore1 == true || qText == true || answertype == true || tfanswer == true || mcanswer == true || mcTextfields == true || youtubeVal == true || vimeoVal == true || tempImgCheck == true || surveyAnswers1 == true) {
        var alertText = "It appears that you have not finished completing question" + question[i].questionNumber + ". Please ensure that you have completed the following question fields.\n";
        if (quizName == true) {
            alertText = alertText + qName;
        };
        if (quizscore1 == true) {
            alertText = alertText + scoreMessage;
        };
        if (qText == true) {
            alertText = alertText + QTextMessage;
        };
        if (answertype == true) {
            alertText = alertText + answerTMessage;
        };
        if (tfanswer == true) {
            alertText = alertText + tfMessage;
        };
        if (mcanswer == true) {
            alertText = alertText + mcMessage;
        };
        if (mcTextfields == true) {
            alertText = alertText + mcFields;
        };
        if (youtubeVal == true) {
            alertText = alertText + ytMessage;
        };
        if (vimeoVal == true) {
            alertText = alertText + vimMessage;
        };
        if (tempImgCheck == true) {
            alertText = alertText + imgMessage;
        };
        if (surveyAnswers1 == true) {
            alertText = alertText + surveyMessage;
        };
        if (quizscore1 == true) {
            alertText = alertText + scoreMessage;
        };
        confirm(alertText);
    };
};

    var numCheck = 1;
var checkQuizQ = function() {
    for (j = 1; j<= qtest.length; j++) {
        numCheck = numCheck + 1;
        if (qtest[j].questionNumber == "1") {
            validateQ("CAT_Custom_3", "CAT_Custom_8", "CAT_Custom_19", "CAT_Custom_18", "CAT_Custom_4", "CAT_Custom_5", "CAT_Custom_6", "CAT_Custom_7", "CAT_Custom_9", "CAT_Custom_10", "CAT_Custom_11", "CAT_Custom_12", "CAT_Custom_230");
        } else if (qtest[j].questionNumber == "2") {
            validateQ("CAT_Custom_20", "CAT_Custom_21", "CAT_Custom_29", "CAT_Custom_26", "CAT_Custom_22", "CAT_Custom_23", "CAT_Custom_24", "CAT_Custom_25", "CAT_Custom_30", "CAT_Custom_31", "CAT_Custom_32", "CAT_Custom_33", "CAT_Custom_231");
        } else if (qtest[j].questionNumber == "3") {
            validateQ("CAT_Custom_35", "CAT_Custom_36", "CAT_Custom_37", "CAT_Custom_40", "CAT_Custom_41", "CAT_Custom_42", "CAT_Custom_43", "CAT_Custom_44", "CAT_Custom_45", "CAT_Custom_46", "CAT_Custom_47", "CAT_Custom_48", "CAT_Custom_232");
        } else if (qtest[j].questionNumber == "4") {
      };
    };
document.getElementById('catcustomcontentbutton').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("qsValidate").style.display = "none";
};
```

Comment: Do you mean j? In the for loop? I have another for loop above this piece of code, which you cannot see, which uses the i variable.

Answer (score 1):

Since `qtest` looks like an array, its index starts from `0` to `length - 1` so when `j` is `length` the value of `qtest[j]` will be undefined.

So change the loop as

```
for (j = 0; j< qtest.length; j++) {
    //
}
```

Comment: I actually start the qtest array at 1.

Comment: @user3593878 - Regular arrays always start at 0 and go till their `length - 1` - You can choose to explicitly store values from index `1` - but it doesn't change the fact that they start from `0`.

Comment: Hmm - So that could be why the error? Even if my array and for loop both look for values starting at 1?

Comment: @user3593878 still the last item in the array will have the index `qtest.length - 1` so try `for (j = 1; j < qtest.length; j++) {}`

Comment: @user3593878 you have an `i` at `var alertText = "It appears that you have not finished completing question" + question[i].questionNumber + ". Please ensure that you have completed the following question fields.\n";`

Comment: So just change it from <= to <  ?

Comment: @user3593878 yes, if you are starting the index from 1 instead of 0... can you use [console logging](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) to see the values in the array... see the console log in http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2y773/1/

Comment: @user3593878 - That's a good catch. it did not fix my issue, but I changed it to use the correct variable.

Comment: @user3593878 can you tell me which line is actually throwing the error... this info will be available in the browser console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58397/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-user3593878).

Comment: I just did a test to see if starting the array at 0 would make a difference and it did not. However when I changed the <= to < I did not get the same error. From what I can tell the script seems to be working, however it is not acting as I want it to.

For some reason my ValidateQ function does not appear to be closed when I look at in my business catalyst developer editor.